# Sum each elements in several lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
list_1 = [11, 22]
list_2 = [33, 44, 55 ,66]
list_3 = [77, 88 ,99]
```

I want to sum each elements in lists. i.e. 11 + 33 + 77, 11 + 33 + 88, … 22 + 33 + 77, 22 + 33 + 88… and put all the sums into a final list

I have these lines:

```
list_1 = [11, 22]
list_2 = [33, 44, 55 ,66]
list_3 = [77, 88 ,99]

result = []

for L_1 in list_1:
    for L_2 in list_2:
        for L_3 in list_3:
            result.append(L_1 + L_2 + L_3)

print result                   # to output all elements
print list(set(result))     # to not showing duplicates
```

The codes work well but looked clumsy. If there are 20  or more lists to take part in the calculation, it doesn’t looked good at all.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Transhuman, thank you for your help. your lines are good for learning. could you please resume your answer?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Thanks, I mis-understood the question.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of combination is called the Cartesian product. You can get it using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

list_1 = [11, 22]
list_2 = [33, 44, 55, 66]
list_3 = [77, 88, 99]

result = {sum(t) for t in product(list_1, list_2, list_3)}
print(sorted(result))
```

**output**

```
[121, 132, 143, 154, 165, 176, 187]
```

You can even use `product` if you don't know in advance how many lists you have:

```
all_lists = list_1, list_2, list_3
result = {sum(t) for t in product(*all_lists)}
```

---

The `product` iterator yields tuples of the items from the iterables that you pass it. We then pass those tuples to the built-in `sum` function to perform the addition.

Here's what the "raw" output from `product` looks like:

```
from itertools import product

list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [3, 4]
list_3 = [5, 6]

all_lists = list_1, list_2, list_3
for t in product(*all_lists):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 6)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: This gives the product, but doesn't the asker want to sum the values instead?

Comment: @Windmill Which it also does

Comment: Does it? Sorry, was just going off the number of values given in the output.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, thank you for the teaching!

Comment: @Windmill The number of items in `result` is small because we've collected them in a set to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(sum, product(*lists))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lists = [11, 22], [33, 44, 55, 66], [77, 88, 99]
>>> map(sum, product(*lists))
[121, 132, 143, 132, 143, 154, 143, 154, 165, 154, 165, 176, 132, 143, 154, 143, 154, 165, 154, 165, 176, 165, 176, 187]
```

Comment: `set(map(sum, product(*lists)))` based on Op's requirements.

Comment: You mean their *"put all the sums into a final list"*?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, very good! thank you for teaching. :)

Comment: No, I mean by the `list(set(result))` in the list line.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That's not in the stated "requirements". Also, it's commented with "to not *showing* duplicates" (emphasis my interpretation). And it's literally not their `result`.

Comment: Nice use of `map`, and I guess it's not too advanced for the OP.